# VS Code - How to use "code completion" on some object that used in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I currently build a back-end using NodeJs.

To make the route, I should code like this:

```
// sever.js
server.route({
    path: '/some/path',
    method: 'GET',
    handler: (request, reply) => {
        return reply.response('trick or treat');
    }
})
```

If I make the route like this, there will be code completion when I type `request` or `reply` and show all of these properties, include the info. Because the intelliSense will recognize it as a member of server object(`handler`'s parameters).

Now, I want to separate the main server and routes. Will be look like this:

```
// server.js
const routes = require('./routes');

server.routes(routes);
```

```
// routes.js
module.exports = [
    {
        path: '/some/path',
        method: 'GET',
        handler: (request, reply) => {
            return reply.response('trick or treat');
        }
    },
    ...
];
```

Now, when I type `request` or `reply`, there is no code completion like before. What I wanted is how to make intelliSense recognise the `request` and `reply` as a member of server object so that there will be code completion, parameter info, etc.

Comment: Use TypeScript. There's no way for code completion to guess what functions are or are not available

Comment: Use Typescript (2). code intellisense  was one of big reasons to use TS for me.

Comment: @nbokmans Okkey. Thanks, I'll learn it